# Time series decomposition: should seasonality be tested prior to decomposition?

Tags: time-series, seasonality, decomposition

Some time series decomposition methods (e.g. `decompose` and `stl`), do not perform any statistical test to test the presence of seasonality prior to the decomposition. In other words, they decompose any time series into three components (trend, seasonal, remainder), even if it is not seasonal. Suppose that we don’t know if a given time series is seasonal or not. We could do two different approaches:

1. Perform a statistical test to test the presence of seasonality. If the test reject the null hypothesis of no seasonality, use the seasonal decomposition method, otherwise smooth the time series with a non-seasonal method.
2. Decompose the time series without worrying if seasonality is present or not

Which one is the best approach?

In my opinion, the second approach is better because if seasonality is present, there is no model misspecification. If seasonality is not present, the estimated seasonal component would be negligible and results will not be affected much. On the other hand, the first approach can lead to a type II error which can bias the estimated trend component severely.

Thank you.